# Assign Materials by UV Island

Tags: materials, uv

Help needed. I am using Blender 2.79 - I have a dress that I modeled and then unwrapped in UV layout. The problem is that I never added any material zones. What I would like to do now is add materials by UV island without having to try to select all those proper polys in 3d menu. Is there a way to add material zones by uv? Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are in your UV Editor, you could select a Polygon Face of any island and then hit L on your keyboard to select the island , after that you could assing a material.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [Select Linked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-linked) command in the viewport and constrain it by seams.
If there aren't seams already on the mesh choose *UV* > *Seams From Islands* in UV editor (when UV map is visible).
With seams available select a face of the mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (or <kbd>L</kbd> if mouse cursor is over the mesh) while in 3D viewport. In operator options (<kbd>F6</kbd>) choose *Seams*.

[image]

Now there will be selected only that part of mesh geometry corresponding to one of the islands.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it works to select the islands. But then when I try to assign the materials, they still all just assign to the entire mesh.

Comment: @VictorCsakany it seems that you selected islands in the UV editor. What this answer assumes is selecting geometry in the viewport, then if there are more than 1 material faces will be assigned to chosen one.